# Permanent access to a usergroup for a usb drive

Tags: usb, permissions, samba, user-management

I have a USB flash drive which gets mounted to /media/pi/76E8-CACF (pi is my main user).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -ld /media/pi/76E8-CACF
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 131072 Jul 23 23:54 /media/pi/76E8-CACF
```

I have created 2 new UNIX users and added them in a usergroup (including pi).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ grep sambagroup /etc/group
sambagroup:x:1003:Space_Legion,pi,Space_Android
```

I want to permanently give rw permissions to this new usergroup.

The end goal is these users to be able to access the contents of the USB using samba.

I am running Raspbian OS, as you probably guessed.

Comment: Raspbian OS is not a supported Ubuntu release, and is not supported on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***One way*** is to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and at the end of the file add a share definition to the default USB mount point parent. Something like this:

```
[USB]
path = /media/pi
read only = No
valid users = @sambagroup
force user = pi
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

*** The only users that will gain access are members of the sambagroup group ( @sambagroup )

*** Once authenticated their identities - for this share anyway - will be changed to pi ( force user = pi ) who is the only user that can traverse the /media/pi folder.

This will allow access to anything mounted under /media/pi. You can make it specific to one particular USB device by changing the path to that device:

```
path = /media/pi/76E8-CACF
```